# What does どれ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does どれ mean in this sentence?

神戸にはもうどれくらいいらっしゃいますか。- How long have you been in Kobe?

Basically, どれ means "which", but what meaning does it have in that sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically, it may be better to remember どれくらい＝how much, how long.

くらい means *(approximate) amount*, so どれくらい means *which amount*, or *what amount of time* = *how long* in the particular context. It can be used for asking other kinds of amount.

- どれくらいの費用がかかりましたか how much did it cost?
- どれくらい歩きましたか how long did you walk? (this is ambiguous between time and distance)